# Is there a way to have unlinked Nodes to not be as spread out in a radius?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

*Note:* I adapted this from Javascript to be Typescript.  Generally everything is in fact javascript.  I am using this in angular, but i believe this to be outside the scope of issues.  I added the [javascript] tag because while this is TS, the answer can be be javascript and adapted.

*EDIT*:  I think the issue may be related to the charge. Charge allows the nodes a moment to set themselves, but i think with it being -130, the nodes not related to anything are just drastically pushed away which I dont like.  I am thinking that I may need to find a way to selectively charge nodes, but i do think that maintaining charge would be uesful

I noticed something which was interesting when running my Forced Directed Graph.  If the Nodes are linked, it creates a nice organic representation of the data in a fluid manor.  Any of the nodes which are not linked, they just sit in a circle around the object, seemingly equally spaced as if all the nodes were unlinked.  One if the issues I had is that the Radius of this non linked Circle is so large that it is outside the viewport.  Is there a Forced Directed way to maybe make this default to be something more easily consumed such as but not limited to a smallar radius or sitting off to the side of the linked object.

Either way, i want to get the unlinked devices to reset within the view port as people dont know about the zooming out necessarily.

I also noticed that if I redraw the screen the nodes will sometimes have a velocity and slowly move off screen which seems incorrect overtime as the grid refreshes.  I am not sure why this occurs.  I think the simulation nodes radius may be related to the below code or the "ticker" variable:

```
this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation().force("charge", d3.forceMainBody().strength(FORCES.CHARGE));
this.simulation.on("tick", function(){ ticker.emit(this); });
```

or possibly even the force "centers" function.

```
this.simulation.force('centers', d3.forceCenter(options.width /2, options.height /2));
```

Ill link a picture showing what occurs (but zoomed out) as well as topology code.

[image: Image showing nodes spread out]

```
import { Link } from './link';
import { Node } from './node';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

const FORCES = {
    GRAVITY: 0.1,
    FRICTION: 0.9,
    CHARGE: -130,
    LINKDISTANCE: 50,
    LINKSTRENGTH: 0.2,
    CHARGEDISTANCE: Infinity,
    THETA: 0.8
};

export class ForceDirectedGraph {

    public ticker: EventEmitter<d3.Simulation<Node,Link>> = new EventEmitter<d3.Simulation<Node,Link>>();
    public simulation: d3.Simulation<any, any>;

    constructor(public nodes: Node[], public links: Link[], options: {width, height}){
        this.initSimulation(options);
    }

    initNodes() {
        if (!this.simulation) {
            throw new Error ('Simulation was noot Initialized.');
        }
        this.simulation.nodes(this.nodes);
    }
    initLinks() {
        if (!this.simulation) {
            throw new Error ('Simlulation was not Initialized');
        }
        this.simulation.force('links', d3.forceLink(this.links).strength(FORCES.LINKSTRENGTH));
    }

    initSimulation(options: any) {
        if (!options || !options.width || !options.height) {
            throw new Error("Missing Options On Initialize");
        }

        if (!this.simulation) {
            const ticker = this.ticker;
            this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody()
                    .strength(FORCES.CHARGE));
            this.simulation.on('tick', function() {
                ticker.emit(this);
            });
            this.initNodes();
            this.initLinks();
        }

        this.simulation.force('centers', d3.forceCenter(options.width / 2, options.height / 2))

        this.simulation.restart();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [radial force](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#forceRadial) and only apply it to the disconnected nodes.

```
this.simulation
    .force('radial', d3.forceRadial(Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 10)
    .strength(d => isConnected(d) ? 0 : 0.2))
```

Where `isConnected` is some function that determines if a node is connected.

Comment: is 'd' a node reference?

Comment: yes. see: https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#radial_strength

Comment: I was doing some preliminary tests.  It actually looks like it works.  I added a property to Node which is determined when i build the links and then I do:  `d => d.hasLink ? 0 : 0.2` and it actually looks pretty good.  I just never to figure out that property would be defined and set to not create additional costs of runtime.   Works well, ill give you the answer.